# How to add HTML Tags to a string inside a UITextView Swift Xcode

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode

Background: When I retrieve a string from a web service, it includes HTML tags. What I get is:

```
"Most children who have chronic ear infections outgrow them over time.<div><br></div><div><br></div><div>test</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>test1</div>").
```

Now, I am displaying this to a UITextView by converting it to an attributedString so the user wouldn't see all the HTML tags. I am converting this string to attributedString like this with two extensions:

```
extension: String { 
var data: Data {
    return Data(utf8)
} 

extension Data {

var attributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

self.textView.attributedText = htmlTagString.data.attributedString

Now, the user will be able to view the textview's attributed text without the HTML Tags. But then when they save it, I am only saving the textView.attributedText.string but by doing that, the string's HTML Tags are all gone but I need to save them as well such as 
 etc.

Question: How do I keep the HTML Tags of a textview's string/text? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    var attributedStringToHtml: String? {
       do {
          let htmlData = try self.data(from:NSMakeRange(0, self.length), documentAttributes:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]);
           return String.init(data: htmlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
       } catch {
           print("error:", error)
           return nil
       }
    }
}
```

Previous swift versions:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    var attributedStringToHtml: String? {
        do {
            let htmlData = try self.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, self.length), documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType])
            return String(data:htmlData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8) 
        } catch { 
            print("error:", error)
            return nil 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get "Type 'String' has no member 'documentType'" error with ".documentType" highlighted in red.

Comment: It's on swift 4, which version of swift are you using?

Comment: oh I am currently using swift 3, if i change to swift 4, i am getting a lot of errors i need to fix.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: In the textview that is being sent to the web service, i am sending: self.textview.attributedText.attributedStringToHtml which is sending the whole <DODCTYPE html> tags with the entire <html><head> etc tags. but that is too much to send. I only need to include things like <br tag or <p. very simple html tags. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

Next all code in Controller file, but first in it

```
self.contact.attributedText = contact.html2Attributed
```

Second in end file

```
extension String {
  var html2Attributed: NSAttributedString? {
    do {
      guard let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return nil
      }
      return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [
        .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
        .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
      ], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
      print("error: ", error)
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:**

```
extension String{
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

**How to Use?**

```
descLbl.attributedText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>This is heading 1</h1><h2>This is heading 2</h2><h3>This is heading 3</h3><h4>This is heading 4</h4><h5>This is heading 5</h5><h6>This is heading 6</h6></body></html>".convertHtml()
```